# How to generate utxo information for a bitcoin transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcore

I'm using bitcore atm and am trying to set up transactions. but I can't find much information on the `txId` & the `script`. I know it says the txId is generated from the transaction, but how can you generate a txId for a transaction which has yet to take place?

Maybe I'm not fully understanding this process fully, is there somebody who understands who could explain it a bit better?

```
var utxo = {
  "txId" : "115e8f72f39fad874cfab0deed11a80f24f967a84079fb56ddf53ea02e308986",
  "outputIndex" : 0,
  "address" : "17XBj6iFEsf8kzDMGQk5ghZipxX49VXuaV",
  "script" : "76a91447862fe165e6121af80d5dde1ecb478ed170565b88ac",
  "satoshis" : 50000
};

var transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()
  .from(utxo)
  .to('1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK', 15000)
  .sign(privateKey);
```

Edit: I posted this with the misunderstanding of how value is counted on the blockchain. I see now that the txid and/or utxos are not of the current transaction but of the previous unspent transactions that the spending address received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction ID is just the hash of the transaction, it doesn't matter if the transaction is incomplete (invalid), or unconfirmed, or confirmed. The wTXID is similar in operation, but only hashes a portion of the transaction.

Comment: I think OP is confused by thinking the UTXO's txid is that of the spending transaction perhaps.

Comment: @PieterWuille You are correct Pieter, I just did an overview of transactions and spending and I didn't fully understand it (still don't but I now understand utxo (unspent outputs). Thank ya'll so much for being patient and not bashing my noob questions. Really do appreciate it.